# Embedded Facebook does not display using Gatsby unless the page is manually reloaded

Tags: reactjs, facebook, embed, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm using Gatsby to build a website that has a "specials" page with embedded Facebook.  The Facebook embed does not display unless I manually reload the page or go directly to the "specials" page (rather than navigating to "specials" from the home page).

I have the Facebook script in my layout.js component file using React-Helmet:

```
export default ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div id={layoutStyles.body}>
      <Helmet>
        // ...other tags
        <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0"></script>
      </Helmet>
      <Navigation />
      <div id={layoutStyles.main}>{children}</div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And in my specials.js file I have the rest of the code for embedding:

```
// ...
render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <p>Scroll to see more specials.</p>
        <div id={styles.facebook} className="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/LakesideMarcell/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/LakesideMarcell/" className="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LakesideMarcell/">Lakeside Lumber &amp; Hardware LLC</a></blockquote>
        </div>
        <p>If you don't see specials here click the link above to see our specials on Facebook.</p>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
export default Specials
```

I've tried moving the script tag around in the code but the result is the same problem.  I also tried using componentDidMount with state, and a function that called window.location.reload(), but I cold not get the page to reload only once.

I've used the same code embedded in a version of the website not using Gatsby and I don't have this issue so it must be something to do with Gatsby.  Is there a way to fix this or reload the page once without user action?

Comment: The Facebook SDK doesn't know that you changed the content of the page so you have to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for the reply.  I'm sure you are right.  But for simplicity at the moment I switched to using the iframe version and that works as expected.